# react-select in an imported component trying to get changed value to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

I am using react-select for the first time and having a bit of trouble figuring this out.

I am creating a US State picker reusable component. Everything is working except I am not able to get the changed value back.

Can someone take a look at this sandbox and see if you can help?  MUCH appreciated.

[image: Edit flamboyant-bird-fj4nz]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use RHF's `<Controller />` component here instead of `register` as `react-select` is an external controlled component. [Here](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingControlledInputs) you can find information about integrating external controlled component.

```
<Controller
  name="state"
  control={control}
  defaultValue={state}
  rules={{
    required: "Please select a State"
  }}
  render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
    <StateDropDown {...field} id="state" />
  )}
/>
```

You also can simplify your wrapper `<StateSelectDropDown />` component by just passing through the props to your `<StyledSelect />` component.

```
export function SelectState(props: any) {
  const options = USStates.map((item: any) => ({
    label: item.value + " - " + item.label,
    value: item.value
  }));

  return (
    <StyledSelect
      {...props}
      styles={styles}
      placeholder="Select a State"
      options={options}
    />
  );
}

export default function StateSelectDropDown(props: any) {
  return <SelectState isSearchable {...props} />;
}
```

[image: Edit xenodochial-lucy-5xnd6]

Comment: I added passing a default value (in case it helps anyone else looking for a solution like this)..  https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-liskov-lyump